# Finding whether an SVG element is visible in the viewport

Tags: svg, intersection

Say I have some SVG that looks like the following. `#canvas` will have some transforms applied:

```
<svg id="viewport" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
    <g id="canvas" transform="scale(0.17)">
        <image class="imageTile" x="0" y="0" width="256" height="256"/>
        <image class="imageTile" x="256" y="0" width="256" height="256"/>
        <image class="imageTile" x="0" y="256" width="256" height="256"/>
        <image class="imageTile" x="256" y="256" width="256" height="256"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

`#canvas` will be draggable, so when I drag a `.imageTile` into view, I will fire off a download.

```
var tiles = Y.all(".imageTile");
for (var i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++) {
    if (the tile is visible - ??) {
        // set its xlink:href attribute
    }
}
```

I know that `getScreenCTM()` will get me an SVGMatrix object, but I don't know how to use that to calculate the intersection. I'm also aware of the `SVGElement.getIntersectionList()` method, but it seems to have some browser compatibility issues. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of [Mr. B. Campin's SVG Open paper](http://www.svgopen.org/2005/papers/VectorAndRasterTilesForMappingApplications/), I figured it out:

```
var tile; // this is your SVG tile node

var svgroot = tile.ownerSVGElement;
var scale = svgroot.currentScale;
var vbParts = svgroot.getAttribute("viewBox").split(" ");
var vbx = parseInt(vbParts[0]);
var vby = parseInt(vbParts[1]);
var vbxu = parseInt(vbParts[2]);
var vbyu = parseInt(vbParts[3]);
var tx = svgroot.currentTranslate.x;
var ty = svgroot.currentTranslate.y;
var svgWidth = parseInt(svgroot.getAttribute("width"));
var svgHeight = parseInt(svgroot.getAttribute("height"));
var svgzoomfactor = vbxu / svgWidth;

var vpRect = svgroot.createSVGRect();
vpRect.x = parseFloat(vbx + (-tx) * (svgzoomfactor) / scale);
vpRect.y = parseFloat(vby + (-ty) * (svgzoomfactor) / scale);
vpRect.width = parseFloat(svgWidth * svgzoomfactor / scale);
vpRect.height = parseFloat(svgHeight * svgzoomfactor / scale);

if (svgroot.checkIntersection(tile, vpRect)) {
    // the tile intersects the viewport!
}
```

Comment: This also has browser compatibility issues. checkIntersection() is not supported in Firefox (maybe others). I think the element's transform tag along with bbox would solve the problem, but I haven't tried it, yet.

Answer (score 1):

[viewportElement api](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74981433/7781527)

viewPortElement api will return null if svg is not displayed

Comment: If it doesn't return null that doesn't mean the element is visible though.