# check whether svg element is visible in a div

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have tried out several ways to check if an svg element is visible on the screen. the svg image is inside a div called "prior".

I am determining the svg viewBox and the svg element's bounding client rectangle to see if the element is in the visible view. the svg element is a rectangle object here.

**HTML**

```
<div  tabindex="0" id="prior" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;overflow:hidden; position: relative;">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
//Get the svg viewBox coordinates
var svg = document.querySelector(prior + ' svg')
var viewBox = svg.viewBox.baseVal;
console.log(viewBox)

// Get the svg element coordinates
var tile = <rect inside the svg>
var tile_bcr = tile.getBoundingClientRect()
console.log(tile_bcr)

//check if svg element coordinates are in svg viewBox
```

When svg is zoomed in, checking for svg element inside svg viewBox is failing. the svg element may or may not be visible in the div when zoomed in.

Some of these solutions have not worked:

[Finding whether an SVG element is visible in the viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554760/finding-whether-an-svg-element-is-visible-in-the-viewport)

https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-translate-from-dom-to-svg-coordinates-and-back-again/

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please be more specific what "have not worked" mean. Have you tried using `getBoundingClientRect` to the SVG element and comparing it with the `div`'s bounding client rect?

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! I was fixated on svg's viewbox, but div's bounding client rect is the right one to compare with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try viewportElement api.
JS

```
var svg = document.querySelector(prior + ' svg');
console.log(svg.children[0].viewportElement)
```

I am trying to take svg's any children and checking whether it is in viewport - it will return svg element if it is rendered and displayed properly or else it will be null.

Example1:(svg is rendered but not displayed)

```
var svg = document.createElement("svg")
svg.innerHTML = '<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />';
document.body.appendChild(svg)
console.log(svg.children[0].viewportElement) //returns null so svg is not displayed in dom
```

Example2:(svg is rendered and displayed)

```
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","svg");
svg.innerHTML = '<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />';
document.body.appendChild(svg)
console.log(svg.children[0].viewportElement) //returns svg element, so svg is displayed properly.
```

Comment: This is working fine in chrome but not in mozilla firefox.

Comment: `svg.viewportElement` doesn't check if an element is visible or not. From [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGElement#svgelement.viewportelement): " The SVGElement which established the current viewport. Often the
 nearest ancestor `<svg>` element. null if the given element is the
 outermost <svg> element."

Comment: svg.innerHTML = '<circle cx="18050" cy="500e10" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />';

Comment: you can see that can you?

Comment: `svg.innerHTML = '<circle cx="18050" cy="500e10" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />';`
I can see that only if i created the "svg"element with specifying the namespace URI - `document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","svg");` @RobertLongson

Comment: I mean with those co-ordinates you won't see it because it won't be within the viewport.

Comment: @RobertLongson my bad, missed to see updates co-ordinates. Yes the solution will fail in this case.

The co-ordinates of the circle goes out of viewBox then it will be not be displayed but my point is that i have written valid co-ordinates and so just making sure it is displayed properly.

Comment: @MOHAMED SIKKANDAR AFZAL M: pardon me, but **`svgElement.viewportElement` neither checks any svg viewBox/HTML viewport intersections  nor  any or visibility!** . Your first example returns `undefined/null` because it doesn't create a proper (namespaced) svg DOM element – hence, there is no svg DOM node existent from which you could read the viewportElement property.  See this [codepen example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/VwBpjXY). Sorry it's just not a valid solution but rather misleading.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Check Svg visibility in DOM element via [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

To check whether a `<svg>` (or any other DOM element) is placed within the boundaries of e.g a wrapping `<div>` we can use an IntersectionObserver like so:

```
const options = {
  root: document.querySelector(".wrap"),
  rootMargin: "0px",
  threshold: 0.5
};

const inViewPortObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    let target = entry.target;
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      target.classList.add("inViewport");
      target.classList.remove("notinViewport");
    } else {
      target.classList.add("notinViewport");
      target.classList.remove("inViewport");
    }
  });
}, options);

const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
inViewPortObserver.observe(svg);
```

But we can't check visibility of svg child nodes this way.
In other words: we can't apply it to **elements within the SvgDOM.**

#### 2. Svg element in `viewBox`

As commented by **@Jan Stránský** you can check a bounding box intersection between the parent `<svg>` and a child element by comparing the `getBoundingClientRect()` values against each other.

```
/**
 * visible in svg viewBox
 */
function checkViewBoxIntersection(svgChildren, threshold = 1) {
  let svg = svgChildren[0].viewportElement;
  let bb0 = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
  let [left0, top0, right0, bottom0] = [bb0.x, bb0.y, bb0.right, bb0.bottom];

  svgChildren.forEach(function (el, i) {
    let bb = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    let [left, top, right, bottom] = [bb.x, bb.y, bb.right, bb.bottom];
    let bboxIntersection =
      left <= right0 - threshold &&
      top <= bottom0 - threshold &&
      bottom >= top0 - threshold &&
      right >= left0 - threshold
        ? true
        : false;

    // in viewport
    if (bboxIntersection) {
      el.classList.remove("notinViewportSvg");
      el.classList.add("inViewportSvg");
    } 
    // not viewport
    else {
      el.classList.add("notinViewportSvg");
      el.classList.remove("inViewportSvg");
    }
  });
}
```

This approach is also a workaround/alternative to [@alexantd's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554760/finding-whether-an-svg-element-is-visible-in-the-viewport#6602739) using `checkIntersection()` – since `checkIntersection()` is currently [**not supported by firefox.**](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_svgsvgelement_checkintersection)

However this approach isn't very precise:
e.g. a `<circle>` bounding box can intersect with the svg viewBox rectangle – while not being visible.

[image]

#### Example 1: div and svg element intersections

```js
function getViewPortEls(els) {
  let log = "";
  els.forEach((el) => {
    let viewPortEl = el.viewportElement;
    log += "#" + el.id + " viewportElement: #" + viewPortEl.id + "; ";
  });
  viewportSpan.textContent = log;
}


/**
 * visible in svg viewBox
 */
function checkViewBoxIntersection(svgChildren, threshold = 1) {
  let svg = svgChildren[0].viewportElement;
  let bb0 = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
  let [left0, top0, right0, bottom0] = [bb0.x, bb0.y, bb0.right, bb0.bottom];

  svgChildren.forEach(function (el, i) {
    let bb = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    let [left, top, right, bottom] = [bb.x, bb.y, bb.right, bb.bottom];
    let bboxIntersection =
      left <= right0 - threshold &&
      top <= bottom0 - threshold &&
      bottom >= top0 - threshold &&
      right >= left0 - threshold
        ? true
        : false;

    // in viewport
    if (bboxIntersection) {
      el.classList.remove("notinViewportSvg");
      el.classList.add("inViewportSvg");
    } 
    // not viewport
    else {
      el.classList.add("notinViewportSvg");
      el.classList.remove("inViewportSvg");
    }
  });
}

/**
 * visible parent HTML DOM element
 **/
const options = {
  root: document.querySelector(".wrap"),
  rootMargin: "0px",
  threshold: 0.5
};

const inViewPortObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    let target = entry.target;
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      target.classList.add("inViewport");
      target.classList.remove("notinViewport");
    } else {
      target.classList.add("notinViewport");
      target.classList.remove("inViewport");
    }
  });
}, options);

const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
inViewPortObserver.observe(svg);
```

```css
.wrap{
  border:2px solid #ccc;
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
}

.svg{
  margin-left:150px;
  width:50px;
}

svg{
  overflow:visible;
  width:20em;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.notinViewport{
    border:4px solid red;
}

.notinViewportSvg{
    opacity:0.2
}

.inViewport{
    border:4px solid green;
}

.inViewportSvg{
    opacity:1
}
```

```html
<p>Move Svg in div (x)<br><input class="inputs" type="range" id="inputMargin" value="0" min="0" max="300" steps="1"></p>

<p>Move Svg in div (y)<br><input class="inputs" type="range" id="inputMarginTop" value="0" min="0" max="300" steps="1"></p>

<p>Move elements in svg (x)<br><input class="inputs" type="range" id="inputTranslate" value="0" min="-200" max="300" steps="1"></p>

<div class="wrap">
  <svg class="svg" id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <symbol id="symbol">
      <rect id="rect" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="green" />
    </symbol>
    <g id="group">
      <svg id="nestedSvg">
        <ellipse id="ellipse" cx="100" cy="10" rx="25" ry="20" fill="purple" />
      </svg>
      <circle id="circle" cx="150" cy="75" r="25" fill="red" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
<p>Svg viewportElements: <span id="viewportSpan"></span> </p>


<script>
  let viewPortEls = [circle, rect, ellipse];
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.inputs');
  inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('input', e => {
      svg1.style.marginLeft = +inputMargin.value + 'px';
      svg1.style.marginTop = +inputMarginTop.value + 'px';
      group.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${inputTranslate.value} 0)`);
      checkViewBoxIntersection(viewPortEls);
      getViewPortEls(viewPortEls)
    })
  })
</script>
```

#### Example 2: intersection by checking `isPointInFill()`

```js
let [xOff, yOff] = [0, 0];
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".inputs");

let checkIntersectionEls = document.querySelectorAll(".checkIntersection");
checkViewPortIntersection(checkIntersectionEls);

inputs.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    xOff = +inpXoff.value;
    yOff = +inpYoff.value;
    let trans = `scale(1) translate(${xOff}, ${yOff})`;
    canvas.setAttribute("transform", trans);
    checkViewPortIntersection(checkIntersectionEls);
  });
});

function checkViewPortIntersection(els, threshold = 1) {
  let svg = els[0].viewportElement;
  let bb0 = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
  let [left0, top0, right0, bottom0] = [bb0.x, bb0.y, bb0.right, bb0.bottom];

  // create tmp rect for inFill checks
  let rectViewport = svg.querySelector("#rectViewport");
  if (!rectViewport) {
    rectViewport = document.createElementNS(
      "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
      "rect"
    );
    rectViewport.id = "rectViewport";
    rectViewport.setAttribute("x", 0);
    rectViewport.setAttribute("y", 0);
    rectViewport.setAttribute("width", "100%");
    rectViewport.setAttribute("height", "100%");
    rectViewport.setAttribute("fill", "transparent");
    svg.insertBefore(rectViewport, svg.children[0]);
  }

  els.forEach(function(el, i) {
    let bb = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    let [left, top, right, bottom] = [bb.x, bb.y, bb.right, bb.bottom];
    let type = el.nodeName;
    let isGeometryEl = el instanceof SVGGeometryElement ? true : false;
    let pathLength = isGeometryEl ? el.getTotalLength() : 0;
    let divisions = 24;
    let checkPoints = [];
    let bboxIntersection =
      left <= right0 - threshold &&
      top <= bottom0 - threshold &&
      bottom >= top0 - threshold &&
      right >= left0 - threshold ?
      true :
      false;
    // check bounding box intersections
    let intersecting = false;
    let style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    // translate transformed coordinates via matrix transform
    let matrix = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse().multiply(el.getScreenCTM());

    if (bboxIntersection) {
      // if image element
      if (!isGeometryEl) {
        intersecting = true;
      }
      // check geometry element intersections
      else {
        let step = pathLength / divisions;
        for (let i = 0; i < divisions && !intersecting; i++) {
          let pt = el.getPointAtLength(step * i).matrixTransform(matrix);
          let inFill = rectViewport.isPointInFill(pt);
          if (inFill) {
            intersecting = true;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if (intersecting) {
      el.classList.remove("notinViewPort");
    } else {
      el.classList.add("notinViewPort");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10em;
}

svg {
  width: 20em;
  overflow: visible;
}

.notinViewPort {
  opacity: 0.2
}

.toolbar {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar">
  <p><label>x offset <input type="range" class="inputs"  id="inpXoff" min="-300" max="200" steps="1" value="-30"></label>
    <label>y offset <input type="range"  class="inputs" id="inpYoff" min="-300" max="200" steps="1" value="15"></label>
  </p>
</div>

<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 150 100">
  <g id="canvas" transform="scale(1) translate(-30, 15)">
    <image class="checkIntersection" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" href="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />

    <image class="checkIntersection" x="200" y="0" width="200" height="100" href="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
    <image class="checkIntersection" x="0" y="100" width="200" height="100" href="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
    <image class="checkIntersection" x="200" y="100" width="200" height="100" href="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
    <rect class="checkIntersection" transform="rotate(-45 200 100)" id="rect0" x="125" y="50" width="100%" height="100" fill="green" />
    <circle class="checkIntersection" cx="200" cy="100" r="25" />
  </g>
  
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="#000" />

</svg>
```

This approach provides a better accuracy but it's also less performant due to rather expensive `getPointAtLength()` and `isPointInFill()` calls.

#### What about [`SVGElement.viewportElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGElement#svgelement.viewportelement) ?

Unfortunately, this won't help - since it's a static/read-only **property of the SVGElement node object.**

From mdn webdocs:

> The SVGElement which established the current viewport. Often the
> nearest ancestor `<svg>` element. null if the given element is the
> outermost `<svg>` element.

Examples: `SVGElement.viewportElement` returns

- the **parent `<symbol>`** when read from the child node's object within symbol. (BTW. a symbol definition is also invisible - so SVGElement.viewportElement doesn't care about visibility)
- the **closest ancestor `<svg>`** in nested svgs
- the **parent `<svg>`** if an element isn't wrapped in a `<symbol>` or nested child `<svg>`
- **null** if read from the outermost svg node object, or if the svg wasn't attached correctly to the DOM – so there's no node object at all (e.g when created via non namespaced `createElement()`)

See example 1.